# How different are Inuktitut and Greenlandic?

Tags: language-comparison, greenlandic, inuktikut, eskimo-aleut-languages

My question is as simple as that. Does anyone (preferably a native speaker) know how different or how mutually intelligible **Inuktitut** and **Greenlandic** (Kalaallisut) are? Both are [Eskimo–Aleut languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eskimo%E2%80%93Aleut_languages).

I have a lot of material in Greenlandic, but far less material in Inuktitut and I was wondering if I could learn Greenlandic and still understand and be understood by someone speaking Inuktitut.

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe Thanks for the info. Well, in a language learning context it will be that I have a lot of material in Greenlandic, but far less material in Inuktitut and I was wondering if I could learn Greenlandic and still understand and be understood by someone speaking Inuktitut.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are mutually intelligible to a large degree. I know that from [Per Langgård](https://learngreenlandic.com/about/), one of the very few proficient second-language speakers of Greenlandic. He said that when he was in Nunavut, he spoke West Greenlandic, people answered in Inuktitut, and it worked quite well.

So there is a lot in common in basic words and the structure of the two languages. But when it comes to more advanced vocabulary, differences are clear. Greenlandic has a huge number of loan words from Danish, while Inuktitut is obviously influenced by English.

Sometimes the Danish origin of loan words is clear, e.g. *sygeplejerske* [ˈsyːəˌplɑjˀʌsgə] means ‘nurse’ in Greenlandic, just like in Danish, and sometimes it's harder to find out, as the word is adapted to Greenlandic phonology, e.g. *palasi* [palasi] means ‘priest’ and comes from Danish *præst* [pʁasd]. On the other hand, part of modern vocabulary is purely Greenlandic, such as *qarasaasiaq* [qɑʁasa:siɑq] ‘computer’, and that's probably understandable to speakers of Inuktitut (the Inuktitut version is ᖃᕋᓴᐅᔭᖅ /qarasaujaq/).

When it comes to basic vocabulary, perhaps the clearest influence of Danish is with numbers. Counting from 1 to 20 goes like this: *ataaseq, marluk, pingasut, sisamat, tallimat, arfinillit, arfineq-marluk, arfineq-pingasut, qulingiluat, qulit, aqqanillit, aqqaneq-marluk, tretten, fjorten, femten, seksten, sytten, atten, nitten, tyve*. As you can see, the Danish numerals are used after 12.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the previous answer, I'd like to support the claim that the two languages are very similar. According to the [Inuktitut Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inuktitut#Greenland), Inuktitut and Greenlandic share a common dialect, Inuktun (more commonly known as Polar Eskimo), which "is a recent arrival in Greenland from the Eastern Canadian Arctic, arriving perhaps as late as the 18th century."

A more direct validation of this is found on the [Greenlandic Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenlandic_language), which states that Greenlandic "is closely related to the Inuit languages in Canada such as Inuktitut."

Given that the two languages share a common dialect that can be understood by speakers of both languages, I'd say Inuktitut and Greenlandic have a high level of mutual intelligibility.